# Pull a value for the following month in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, google-sheets-dates

I have a list of values, and they are all for a variety of months (Jan 2018, Feb 2018, &c.). Google Sheets automatically converts these values into 1/1/2018 and so on. Is there a formula I can use to grab the value of the month following today? For example:

Dec 2017 - 10

Jan 2018 - 11

Feb 2018 - 12

Mar 2018 - 13

If I open the sheet today (January 26th, 2018), I want the formula to pull `12` from February.  I hope this makes sense. Basically, I'm looking for a `Today()` code, but for "this month" and then to add one, so it becomes "next month".

Comment: Asked and answered, but for the sake of the internet(?), Sheets has a dedicated formula for the end of last month, so a formula for this month's 1st could be `=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1` —that is; the last day of last month, plus 1 day.  So to get the first day of _next_ month one could use `=EDATE(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,1)`. See also the Help Center function reference for [TODAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984), [EOMONTH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093044), [EDATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092974).

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I found an answer online after much searching. Here's what the formula looks like on my sheet, if anyone else is interested:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX($A$5:$A$41,MATCH(TRUE,$A$5:$A$41>=TODAY(),0)), A5:B41, 2, FALSE)
```

There's probably a way to optimize it somehow, but it's working so I'm happy.